# Empty character in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, char, for-loop, spaces

I'm creating some code that will find a space between characters, and use the characters before the space and the ones after it. These characters are stored in a NSString. Here is what I have so far, however, it's not seeing the empty character.

```
    NSString *tempTitle = self.title;
unsigned int indexOfSpace; // Holds the index of the character with the space
unsigned int titleLength = (unsigned int)self.title.length; // Holds the length of the title
for (unsigned int count = 0; count < titleLength; count++)
{
    if ([tempTitle characterAtIndex:count] == "") // If the character at the index is blank, store this and stop
    {
        indexOfSpace == count;
    }
    else // Else, we keep on rollin'
    {
        NSLog(@"We're on character: %c", [tempTitle characterAtIndex:count]);
    }
}
```

I've tried `nil` , empty string ("") and " " but no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: `indexOfSpace == count;` contains a double equal sign. Did you mean for that to be a single equal sign?

Comment: Oops, I did not hehe. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your space character should be in single quotes, not double quotes. Single quotes get you the char type in C. (Double quotes create a string literal, which essentially functions as a `char *` and will never pass your comparison.)

`-[NSString characterAtIndex:]` returns a type `unichar`, which is an `unsigned short`, so you should be able to compare this directly to a space character `' '`, if that's what you want to do.

Note that nil and empty string, are not useful here-- neither are actually characters, and in any case your string will never "contain" these.

You should see also the NSString methods for finding characters in strings directly, e.g. `-[NSString rangeOfString:]` and its cousins. That prevents you from writing the loop yourself, although those are unfortunately a little syntactically verbose.

Comment: Ah this worked! Thanks! I will look into the rangeOfString method, if it's as verbose as you're saying, I may just keep my method of things, as it's working.

Comment: If you're doing this more than once and want a simpler interface to it, you could consider adding a "category" (search for this) to NSString that provides the functionality in one transparent place.